# How to support key code function in Vue.js for smart tv app

Tags: vue.js, tizen

I am new at Vue.js.i want to support remote key functionality in Vue.js. So please let me know how to do the app for smart tv.

Answer (score 0):

You can devlop Web application for TV following the tutorial:
https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/get-started/tv/first-app

Basing on [this site](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include) you can just import vue.js file in your application with:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
```

and use the necessary Vue.js features in Tizen application.

Regarding using a TV-related features, you can check the list of available features [here](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/tv/index.html#TV%20Controls). From your question I cannot guess which module exactly you would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [caph.js](https://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/tv/caphdocs/index.html) can be used, but it is available only in jquery and angular.
vue and jquery don't mix well together.

```
//you can add your keyboard keycodes as well(in place of 1,2,3,4)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.caph.focus.init(function(nearestFocusableFinderProvider, controllerProvider) {
        controllerProvider.setKeyMap({
            LEFT: 1,
            RIGHT: 2,
            UP: 3,
            DOWN: 4
        });
    });
 });
```